# rpy2 works good in PyCharm and doesn't work in .exe file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze, rpy2

I am making an app using rpy2 library in Python 3.6.1. Everything works great when I am running the script from PyCharm but in .exe file there is a problem. When I click on the button (I am using tkinter for GUI) I don't get any statistics calculated in rpy2 (and again, everything works in PyCharm).
I used cx_freeze to convert to .exe file. 
Does anyone have the idea what is the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A minimal Python code showing the problem (a simplification of your actual code to show the specific portion that isn't working as expected) would probably help a lot any person trying to answer your question.

Comment: Solved: some libraries from R which I used in code weren't copied in folder with .exe file; when I did this manually everything works !