# Unable to use .exe frozen with cx_Freeze on another pc with the following error related to rpy2

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, rpy2

I created a small program with rpy2 to import R in Python and packaged it with cx_Freeze. Then I tested it on my development PC. It works well. However, once I copy my .exe to another PC with a similar OS (Windows 10), the same python (3.7) and R version (3.5.2), the following error message jumps out:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "D:\software\Python3.7.3\lib\site- 
packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py",line 14, in run
File "D:\software\Python3.7.3\lib\site- 
packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py",line 26, in run
File "TR_SNP.py", line 32, in <module>
File "D:\plot.py",line 23, in <module>
dplR = importr('dplR')
File "D:\software\Python3.7.3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py",line 453,in importr
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError
```

It seems like something is wrong with the R lib import.

I tried to search for the answer. Here is one that I think would be similar to my problem: [rpy2 works good in PyCharm and doesn't work in .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391537/rpy2-works-good-in-pycharm-and-doesnt-work-in-exe-file)

However, that answer does not provide details like where I should put the R libs.

Comment: Please post the error message with full traceback as text, not as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Comment: Revised accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The frozen application probably does not look for the R installation at the right place on the target PC. Try to add the following lines to your main application:

```
import platform
import rpy2.situation
lib_path = rpy2.situation.get_rlib_path(r_home, platform.system())
print(lib_path)
```

This will display the location where the application is looking for the R lib. This path (and probably the whole r_home) should exist on the target PC and contain a compatible R installation.

If the path is wrong, you need to tell the frozen application where the R installation is located on the target machine using something like

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = path_to_r_home_on_target_machine
```

But this will be difficult as you will not know in general where the R installation is located. You could try to add the following lines to your application (not sure if it works):

```
import sys    
import os
import rpy2.situation
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # The application is frozen
    # reset R_HOME and try to find a R installation using the fallback mechanisms
    del os.environ['R_HOME']
    os.environ['R_HOME'] = rpy2.situation.get_r_home()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I agree with you that the application may not be able to find the path to the R packages. But I'm not sure if adding R_HOME would work as I tried to change the environment variable in the target pc and the error was still there. So I think it should be somehow the problem to find the specific R libs or packages. Then I also checked the availability of the R libs and packages on the target pc, they are work on well in R.

Comment: Could you please kindly check the link in my question about a similar issue, the author somehow solved the issue by adding the corresponding R libs to the freeze folder. While no detail info about where to put them..