# How to set up rpy2 to build it into an .exe file with CX_Freeze?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze, rpy2

I am trying to build an exe file from a program, which includes some rpy2 functions. To simplify this, i wrote a basic script, which will open a tkinter window saying "Hello World". This works fine.

Now to build up on this, in the next step I included imports of rpy2.objects (only included, did not use!), the program in PyCharm works, but the .exe file won't do anything.

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839193/unable-to-use-exe-frozen-with-cx-freeze-on-another-pc-with-the-following-error) it should be somehow managable to build rpy2 into an .exe file.

What am I missing? Here is the script:

```
import tkinter as tk

# with these two lines active the exe file will not work. 
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages

window = tk.Tk()

greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello World", width=150, height=10)
greeting.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The cause is probably what `pyinstaller` calls *hidden imports*. There is a very useful section in the documentation called *When things go wrong*. I suggest you work through it.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you! In my case i tried working with CX_Freeze instead of pyinstaller, but as there seem to be documented solutions, I will give pyinstaller a try.

Comment: The problem is likely to be similar. Both tooIs use static analysis to detect imports, which means you have to tell them about any dynamic ones.

Comment: Try to run your executable from a terminal / `cmd` prompt and redirect the output into a file: `yourprogram.exe > output.txt` Do you see any error message inside `output.txt` then?